# Display database information as check boxes

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database setup with permissions YES if user has access to this permissions NO if user doesn't have access to this permission. I want to change these answers depending on whether or not a checkbox is ticked for a user. I would like the YES answers to display as a ticked checkbox and the No answers to display as an empty checkbox. How can I do this as my database currently is outputting YES or NO as results for the user.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "databasename";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT adduser, edituser, removeuser, unlockallfiles, viewlocked, filepermissions FROM departments";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table class='table table-hover'><tr style='font-size:18px;'><th>Add User</th><th>Edit User</th><th>Remove User</th><th>Unlock All</th><th>View Locked</th><th>File Permissions</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr style='font-size:16px;'><td>".$row["adduser"]."</td><td>".$row["edituser"]."</td><td>".$row["removeuser"]."</td><td>".$row["unlockallfiles"]."</td><td>".$row["viewlocked"]. "</td><td>" .$row["filepermissions"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "There are 0 clients in the system matching your search criteria";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

How can I get the data YES to display as ticked checkbox and NO to display as empty checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace corresponding code lines in yours with the one below:

```
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       echo "<tr style='font-size:16px;'>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["adduser"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "")  ."></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["edituser"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "") . "></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["removeuser"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "") . "></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["unlockallfiles"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "")  ."></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["viewlocked"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "") . "></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox'". ($row["filepermissions"] == 'Yes' " checked" : "") . "></td>";
       echo "</tr>";                                  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr style='font-size:16px;'><td>".($row["adduser"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox"/>')."</td><td>".($row["edituser"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox" />')."</td><td>".($row["removeuser"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox"/>')."</td><td>".($row["unlockallfiles"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox"/>')."</td><td>".($row["viewlocked"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox"/>'). "</td><td>" .($row["filepermissions"]=='Yes'?'<input type="checkbox" checked/>':'<input type="checkbox"/>'). "</td></tr>";
```